# How to fetch the name of an S3 bucket in Laravel using Storage::disk('s3')

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-storage

I am trying to fetch the bucket name of my S3 Bucket on AWS. I have it in my environment file, but I wish to use it in my code without fetching it from the environment file or config. Is there any way to fetch this information using Storage::disk('s3')?

Comment: I would ask, why other than you want to? That is specifically what the config variables are for. Pulling from the config is exactly what the Storage class uses to know your bucket. Don’t over complicate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the bucket name by using this

```php
Storage::disk('filesystem_name')->getAdapter()->getBucket()
```

Answer (score 0):

it is the part of config so you can access it...

```
config('filesystems.disks.s3.bucket');
```